# Can .ready() event be used on other tags than document

Tags: jquery

Can .ready() event be used on other tags than document?
example:

```
$("#test").ready(function() {
  $("#test").click(function () {
    alert("test");
  });
});
```

Comment: why would you need to? If the document has been loaded that means the entire DOM is ready to be manipulated, unless you are loading in content dynamically? In which case you can just use the $('.my_class').live('click', function() {}); inside the document.ready event handler to bind events to DOM that might not yet be loaded in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting [`.ready()`'s documentation's page](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) :

> The `.ready()` method can only be
>   called on a jQuery object matching the
>   current document

*The selector can be omitted, but it won't change a thing : it'll still work on the document.*

Answer (score 1):

in my own opinion  $("#test").ready means that you check that #test is loaded in dom or not. the point @ZeSimon have that if document load then it's sure that #test is included in dom. but sometime content come from ajax request then it's not loaded in dom and not work if you call click event on them.

the length > 0 can be used to check that #test is exist instead of used ready on them because no-sense their to check using ready event.

if your #test come from ajax request then you have some option

1. bind the click event on them
2. use live('click') to attach a event for content [who maybe come through ajax request]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but it will fire at the same time as $(document).ready() anyway, so what would be the point?